# How to Implement a Database Cache Framwork in Java

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I wants to implement a cache framework to display the contents of a database table to users on 
 every request. There is already Ehcache in Hibernate. But i wants to implement my own. So i need a 
 tutorial how database cache work and algorithm to develop in java.

```
public class CacheElement {

private Object objectValue;

private Object objectKey;

private int index;

   private int hitCount;

.
. // getters and setters
.
}

public final synchronized void addElement(Object key,Object value) {

   int index;
   Object obj;

   // get the entry from the table
   obj = table.get(key);

  // If we have the entry already in our table then get it and replace only its value.
  if (obj != null) {
  CacheElement element;

  element = (CacheElement) obj;
  element.setObjectValue(value);
  element.setObjectKey(key);

  return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the [built-in hibernate caching](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/introduction-to-hibernate-caching/‎)?

Comment: No. I'm suppose to build a new one.

Comment: Use the existing as a guide then?

Comment: I unable to find a good tutorial for that, or documentation. I know this is so easy once i'll understand the algorithm.

Comment: You won't find a goot tutorial on that because the best thing to do is to avoid reinventing the wheel. And no, it's not easy at all. If you have to ask, then you're not ready to implement such a cache.

Comment: What is the cons/minus-points in the existing cache-framework that make you think you need a new one ?

Comment: I got an assignment this as requirement round, to implement. I know it's possible with HashMap but i still don't experienced with that.

Comment: Your code is looking pretty good so far for homework grade work.  Just make a getter which looks in the Map first, and then queries the database if the entry does not exist there.  Done, at least B quality :)

Comment: You can use a `WeakHashMap` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html if you want it to get rid of stale references.